# Replacing State variable names in odb with python

Tags: python, string, binary, abaqus

In Abaqus I have my own material description (VUMAT). This VUMAT generates State Variables that are named SDV1, SDV2 etc. These variables are stored in binary .odb file with other output data in abaqus. Because I have huge number of these I would like to give them meaningful name like S1,S2,E1,E2 etc. so when .odb is viewed in Abaqus viewer it would be clear which variable is which.

Now, abaqus provides python interface to read and write to that .odb file. But as far as I could search I could not find a away to rename those variables. When I try to change them I get read only error.

Therefore, I tried opening the .odb with Notepad++ and found out that if replace all SDV entries in that file manually to what I want and save it. The names would also change in in Abaqus Viewer. That's very good!

But I would like to automate this process. So I wrote a python script to read the initial .odb, replace the SDVs and save altered .odb as a different file.

```
import sys
with open('User.odb','rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
    if b"SDV2" in content:
        print('Found')
        content = content.replace(b'SDV2',b'works')
with open('User.temp.odb','wb') as fw:
    fw.write(content)
```

But when I open the new .odb in abaqus viewer I get the following message:

> ***ERROR: The Abaqus database file is corrupt. If this file was transferred from another machine using FTP or equivalent, ensure that
>   the file was copied using the binary mode instead of ASCII mode.

Moreover, currently, this code also replaces SDV20, how to avoid that and replace just SDV2 and not parts of SDV20, SDV21 etc.?

What i'm missing? I'm using python 2.7.

**EDIT:**

If ODB is opened in HEX editor the following pattern can be seen:
For SDV9 followed by SDV10:

```
04 53 44 56 39 00 00 00 05 53 44 56 31 30 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

it can be observed that the encoding starts with number of characters. 04 for SDV9 and 05 for SDV10 followed by NULL values. 3 for SDV1 to SDV9 and 6 for the rest.  I tried changing SDV9 part to be:

```
05 53 44 56 39 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

and it gave me the same error, while changing SDV10 part to be:

```
05 53 44 56 39 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

works perfectly fine. If anyone is familiar with this, help would be appreciated.

**EDIT2:**

My code does not work because the new variable should be of exactly the same length as the old one. If the length matches then there is no problem. Shorter variables can have spaces after them to obtain the required length of the characters.

By using the code suggested by SSchneid, I was able to match exact SDVs for replacement not including parts of the longer ones.

The standard method to add field variables involving FieldOutput() and addData() is not a nice solution as it duplicates already existing SDVs with a different name. It increases the size of odb substantially for very large analyses. Unless there is a way to delete the old ones.

Of course we could go further by outputting the wanted variables to a separate text file straight from the subroutine. Then by using that text file generate new Field output inside odb. The text file could be deleted afterwards. And all this without requesting the SDV output.

Or the SDV output could be requested to the .fil file and then that could be assembled back to odb using FieldOutput() and addData(). But these are very hacky solutions that require lots of writes to disk and lots of lines of code to parse the output text files.

I'm leaving this tread unanswered, until a complete solution will be posted or I figure it out by my self (in this case I will post an answer hare)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your code `b'SDV2'` and `b'works'` have different length. I assume that won't work.

Comment: Yes this is correct. The lengths must match in order for it to work. Though I was unsuccessful in increasing the lengths by looking at the encoding pattern and trying to replicate it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is very creative, but there is a "standard" way to achieve your goal using Abaqus Python API:

```
frame.FieldOutput(name='works', description='this is a vector', type=VECTOR).addData(position=INTEGRATION_POINT, instance=grout_instance, labels=elementLabels, data=elementData)
```

In your code I observe two possible error:

1. the length of the old and new names ('SDV2' and 'works') mismatches.
2. the binary data section of the ODB file may include 4 consequent bytes which accidentally match 'SDV2'. In this case your script override those bytes and corrupt the whole file.

### Edit1

1. Since Abaqus doesn't provide any method to delete existing fields (for consistency reason as they said), if you want do prevent duplication by using the `addData` method, it is necessary to create a new ODB and copy the fields there. Then you can delete the old file. We have been using this method for a year. The benefit is that you can create vector or tensor from different SDVs for better visuallization.
2. To fix the possible error I mensioned before (length mismatch & unintended replacement), you can use `find` instead of `replace`.

You can try this code

```
content = bytearray(content)
old2new={b'SDV2':b'work'} # add more renaming patterns as you need
for oldn, newn in old2new.items():
  i = content.find(oldn) 
  # or using regex pattern:
  # re.search(oldn, content).start()
  content[i:i+len(newn)] = newn
```

The other codes follow your script. I assume that you just need to replace only one occurance of each name in the file. Otherwise please use the [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) method of `re`.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the "standard" way creates new Field Variables. I already have 36 of SDVs, if I create new ones this number will double. I can't delete the old ones so the file size of my odb will increase a lot. Especially for large analyses. Currently I just replace the name of my SDVs with the code I posted in my question. I just have to be sure that new variable is of exact length as the old one. In this way I am limited to only 4 symbols, what is not sufficient. But very fast and simple. Though would be nice to encode new variable names properly in to the odb.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, didn't think about copying everything to new ODB. Now it makes sense to use the addData method! The code you provided still corrupts the odb if lengths of newn is longer than oldn. Anyways I will try to use the addData method as I could put to use the ability to create tensors and vectors!

Answer (score 1):

A problem is, that you match everything that starts with SDV2. Which means everything that has SDV2 at the beginning will return positive no matter what follows.

The best way to solve matching problems in my opinion is to use regular expressions with re:

```
import re
import sys
with open('User.odb','rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
    content = re.sub('\\bSDV2\\b', 'works', content)
with open('User.temp.odb','wb') as fw:
    fw.write(content)
```

I bet there is a way to do it without re in the way you proposed.

Comment: Yes, indeed, your way replaces exactly what I want. But, Abaqus viewer still gives the error message. It's super weird because if I do it manually it's fine. What does the read and write in python save differently compared to editing it in Notepad++?

Comment: To me, although I am definitely not an expert it sounds like an encoding problem, but since I have no experience with Abaqus viewer this is only a guess.

Comment: Apparently, it has to have the same length as the initial string. Otherwise it won't work. I can replace additional characters with spaces if my new string is shorter. If my new string is longer, for now, there is nothing I can  do. Though abaqus is using even longer names for some variables.

The Notepad++ method worked because I tried replacing 'SDV10' with 'works' and both have the same amount of characters.

I wonder where the information about char length is stored.